# Как правильно оперировать с датами в Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, дата, swift3, swift4

Всем привет! Мне нужна помощь. Пытаюсь выполнить задание по работе с датами. Swift изучаю не так давно. 
Суть в том , что нужно создать дату в формате ISO. С этим я разобрался :

```
var date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
```

Выводит что-то типо : 2018-02-25T15:51:51+03:00

1. Как сделать так, чтобы в конце вместо +03:00 , отображалось Z
2. Как вывести начало следующего дня в этом формате?
3. Как вывести начало и конец текущей недели в этом же формате?
4. Как вывести начало следующего месяца?

Пытался разобраться с dataComponents, но не получилось реализовать то, что хотел и в определенном формате! Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для форматирования в ISO используйте ISO8601DateFormatter:

```
let date = Date()

let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]

let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
// пример: dateString = "2018-02-26T08:53:37.642Z"
```

Чтобы получить дату следующего дня:

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let nextDayDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)!
// Начало дня:
let startOfDay = calendar.startOfDay(for: nextDayDate)
```

Остальное по аналогии.

Comment: Спасибо, прогресс уже есть. Но у меня какая то путаница с датами. Я считываю дату с dataPickerView. Я сделал так, как вы мне сказали. 1 день прибавить я смог. 1 месяц прибавить тоже смог, но нужно вывести начало следующего месяца и вот тут возникают проблемы.
` var startMonthDay: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(bySetting: .day, value: 1, of: "вот тут я не очень понял что указать")!
    }`
Плюс , когда я пытаюсь применить к дате пикера и +1 месяц и начало месяца, то срабатывает только +1 месяц, а вторая функция пишет что-то типо unused date.

Comment: вот моя функция +1 месяца. 
`var startOfMonth : Date {
         return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: startOfDayAtUTC)!
    }`
Соответственно, меняю дату при нажатии на кнопку вот так: 
        `let curDate = picker.date
        let finalDate = curDate.startOfMonth
        let dateString = formatter.string(from: finalDate)
        datePickerText.text = "\(dateString)"`

Comment: @NeoGeniy возьмите нужные компоненты для начала следующего месяца и получите дату:

`let nextMonthComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: nextMonthDate)
let startOfMonth = calendar.date(from: nextMonthComponents)`

Comment: Можно с Вами как-то по почте списаться? Я не очень понял, что мне это даст и как это связать с текущим выбором в dataPickerView, а также в каком месте брать все эти компоненты.

Comment: У меня получилось следующий месяц правильно вывести. Я использовал календарь и dataComponents. Как мне быть с выводом начала и конца недели, от текущей даты? Например если задать 27 февраля 2018 года, то как получить 26 февраля, как начало недели и 4 марта, как конец недели?

Comment: Все сделал, спасибо за помощь!)